# Specify ApplicationName when using ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

This tool is supposed to configure users and roles etc., but when I use it on a new web site, with a new *aspnetdb* database, it adds a record to the `aspnet_Applications` table with the `ApplicationName` and the `LoweredApplicationName` fields set to `/`.  I think it would make more sense if it actually used the application name, i.e. the web site name.  Can I safely just change the application name?  Is there a better way of configuring these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do change the app name in the database - you need to update your web.config file also to reflect the change.

Everywhere you see something like:

```
<add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteDB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"/>
```

your need to update the applicationName attribute: applicationName="/" with applicationName="your app name"